# Restrict tab order to a single user control

Tags: c#, winforms

Tab index focus go to the parent control when i used it in child user control.
How can we stay the focus in the child user control only

Comment: Hi, i just want to restrict the tab index navigation in my child user control.is there any way to do it..?

Comment: Your questions says other way

Comment: Boss is there any way to do it..?

Comment: override the processDialogKey method .and use this in child user control and it wont go to parent.

protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData != Keys.Tab)
            {
                return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
            }
            this.ButtonsPanel.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, false, true);
            return false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can do that by opening the properties panel, for the controls you don't want to navigate with tab, and setting TabStop to false. But I'm not sure if that solve your particular situation.

Comment: In WPF we can restrict that one using KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle".Is there any other way in windows forms

Comment: In Winforms, no. The other thing you can play with is TabIndex, you can set indexes on each control, and it will move the focus in the specified order. But here you should be careful, as the index is valid only inside the parent control.

Comment: override the processDialogKey method .and use this in child user control and it wont go to parent.

protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData != Keys.Tab)
            {
                return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
            }
            this.ButtonsPanel.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, false, true);
            return false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

This kind of action is wrong. The focus will always change to the controls your using on the UI. By forcing a focus to the tab index creates more problems.

For example:
Adding a new action to your control, that when user activates it, it focuses the tab index. Soon you'll realize that you can't use properly any of the controls on your custom control, because the focus is always switched to the tab index control.

If you want to keep the focus on the tab index, so the user can select between the tabs with arrow keys, you should do it the other way:

Edit parent form's property `KeyPreview` to `true`. Add a `KeyPress` event to your form and do the tab switching on the event, instead.

Answer (score 0):

override the processDialogKey method .and use this in child user control and it wont go to parent.

protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
        {
            if (keyData != Keys.Tab)
            {
                return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
            }
            this.ButtonsPanel.SelectNextControl(ActiveControl, true, true, false, true);
            return false;
        }